# cookiecutter-django production deploy with Gunicorn / uWSGI and Nginx

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami, cookiecutter-django

Why would I not be able to access port 8000 through Gunicorn, if I can through Django's development server.

The docs mentioned that production deploy with Gunicorn / uWSGI and Nginx has been successfully done, although no steps. I have been looking at external guides to do a production deploy of Django.

I can run this Gunicorn command and starts listening. I am not able to access the port 8000 for some reason. I can access port 8000 publicly when I do `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

```
gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --name project_django_cookie_cutter --user=$NON_ROOT_USER --group=$NON_ROOT_USER --log-level=debug
```

I am using the Django stack packaged by Bitnami.

I have been following this tutorial last since Gunicorn has not failed to run: https://realpython.com/development-and-deployment-of-cookiecutter-django-on-fedora/

I have tried going through these guides: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/
https://realpython.com/django-nginx-gunicorn/
https://www.pybloggers.com/2016/01/development-and-deployment-of-cookiecutter-django-on-fedora/
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dajngo-with-nginx-gunicorn-aaf8431dc9e0

Comment: Which part of your question involves GCP? What docs or guides have you followed?

Comment: I am using the Django stack packaged by Bitnami on the GCP marketplace that is deployed on GCE. I have updated my question with docs that I have gone through.